# Spring Data Rest One to One Mapping Error on GET request

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data REST with Spring Boot and have a particular problem where when I make a GET request for a *Customer* who has an associated *Address*, I get the following error in the browser:

> > There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> >     org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Could not locate field name [message] on class [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not locate field name [message] on class [java.lang.Long] (through reference chain:....

I have given a basic example of the code below and have removed code for purposes of brevity:

```
public class Customer {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
    ....
}

public class Address {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;
    ....
}
```

However, when I have a *Customer* with no *Address* associated with it, then the GET request seems to be fine.

Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: I have corrected the mapping and now it reflects my original code so issue is still occuring -great spot

Comment: Where does message came from? Do you have a `column` `message` in you Database? Could you show some more fields of `Address`?

Answer (score 0):

Are the attributes in your code annotated like in the example? `@Id` should be used on primitive types or the Wrapper-Type.

The property `mappedBy` should reference an attribute in the other class that is e.g. the `id`. In your example i can't see the references attribute `message`.

Did you try

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

in your Customer-Class?

Comment: Please see in question section for comment.